# How to save multiple records in a one to many relation laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to save multiple records in a one to many relationship. However I could not with several research and many attempts

Firstly these are my models

Donor Model

```
    class Donor extends Model
     {
         use HasFactory;

         protected $table ='donors';
         protected $fillable = ['name','description'];

         public function assets()
              {
       
             return $this->hasMany(Asset::class);

         }

         public static $rules = [
             'name' => ['required','string','unique:donors'],
             'description' => ['required','string'],
         ];

     }
```

Asset Model

```
    class Asset extends Model
 {
         use HasFactory;

         protected $table ='assets';
         protected $fillable = ['donor_id','name','quantity','unit_price'];

           
         public function donor()
         {
       
             return $this->belongsTo(Donor::class);

         }


         public static $rules = [
             'donor_id' => ['required','integer'],
             'name' => ['required','string'],
             'quantity' => ['required','integer'],
            'unit_price' => ['required'],
         ];

     }
```

Asset Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $donor = $request->input('donor_id');
      
        $quantity =  $quantity = $request->input('quantity', []);
        $quantityArray = [];

        foreach($quantity as $qty){
            $quantityArray[] = ['quantity' => $qty];

        }

        $name =  $request->input('name', []);
        $nameArray = [];

        foreach($name as $nm){
            $nameArray[] = ['name' => $nm];

        }

        $unitprice = $request->input('unit_price', []);
        $unitpriceArray = [];

        foreach($unitprice as $up){
            $unitpriceArray[] = ['unit_price' => $up];
          

        }

        $data[] = [...$quantityArray,...$nameArray,...$unitpriceArray];

        // Attempt 1
        Asset::create(['donor_id'=> $donor , $data]
        );
        
          // Attempt 2
        Asset::create(['donor_id'=> $donor] + $data]
       );
        
        // Attempt 3
         Asset::create(['donor_id'=> $donor,
        'unit_price' => $up,
         'name' => $nm,
        'quantity' => $qty]);

        return redirect()->route(static::PREFIX_ROUTE . 'index')
            ->withFlashSuccess(__('was successfully created.'));
    }
```

In my first Attempt 1 and Attempt 2
the donor id was inserted once in the assets table however the content of $data array does not

In my third Attempt 3
the donor id, unit price, name and quantity were inserted once

I would like to seek assistance on how to save multiple records

Below is an additional dd result of $request->all();

```
 array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "VlSOGgIS6KzrDpCmTtGJDnYLbNzby38FHAdUV2I5"
  "donor_id" => "1"
  "name" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "speed boat"
    1 => "Laptops"
    2 => "Trailer"
  ]
  "quantity" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "5"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "2"
  ]
  "unit_price" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "4"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "2"
  ]
]
```

Posted Data

```
<form action="{{ route("asset.store") }}" method="POST" >
        @csrf
       
       

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                Add Asset
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">

            <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('donor_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
            <label for="donor_id">@lang('Donor')</label>
                                    <select name="donor_id" name="donor_id" class="form-control" required>
                                        @foreach($donors as $donor)
                                            <option value="{{ $donor->id }}" @if($donor->id == old('donor_id', $donor->donor_id))selected="true"@endif> {{ $donor->name }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
            @if($errors->has('donor_id'))
                <em class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $errors->first('donor_id') }}
                </em>
            @endif
           
        </div>

       
            <table class="table" id="assets_table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Assets Name</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Unit Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                     
                        <tr id="asset0">
                               
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control"/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"/>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" name="unit_price[]" class="form-control"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                       
                            <tr id="asset1"></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button id="add_row" class=" pull-left">+ Add Row</button>
                        <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right ">- Delete Row</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save">
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do save the relationship this way:

```
$donor = Donor::find($request->input('donor_id'));

// Do the processing of your assets data
// ...


// Save the assets in the donor 
$donor->assets()->saveMany([
    new Asset($assetData1),
    new Asset($assetData2),
]);
```

Documentation here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

I'm not saying it is the most elegant way, but something like this should work (I'm assuming you have a value in each key of each posted array):

```
<?php

$donor = Donor::find($request->input('donor_id'));
$assets = [];

$quantity = $quantity = $request->input('quantity', []);
$name = $request->input('name', []);
$unitprice = $request->input('unit_price', []);

// Instantiate each asset object
foreach ($quantity as $key => $qty) {
    $assets[] = new Asset([
        'unit_price' => $unitprice[$key],
        'name' => $name[$key],
        'quantity' => $qty
    ]);
}

// Save the assets in the donor
$donor->assets()->saveMany($assets);
```

If you can retrieve how many entry are posted, I would rather use a for loop.

Comment: could you please provide example as you said // Do the processing of your assets data. do you mean this $data[] = [ 
        'donor_id'=>$request->input('donor_id'),
     'unit_price'=>$request->input('unit_price'),
    'name'=>$request->input('name'),
    'quantity'=>$request->input('quantity'),];

Comment: and then $donor->assets()->saveMany([
    new Asset($data),
  
]); I'm not quite sure how to do it right

Comment: I am beginning to see that the concept you provided above is useful. I would like to see a complete example. I believe I would follow along

Comment: The variables $assetData1, $assetData2, etc... should be an array of the data you want to insert in your asset object.
You don't have to provide the donor_id. It is automatically set from the donor object when you do the saveMany() method

Comment: could you please check $data[] = [
              
            'name'=> $request->input('name'),
            'quantity'=> $request->input('quantity'),
            'unit_price'=> $request->input('unit_price'),
         
         ]; if it correct

Comment: and the foreach loop              $assets = [];
            foreach ($data as $keys => $items) {
            
                $assets[] = new Asset($items);
              
            }

            $donor->assets()->saveMany($assets); still not get it right. could you improve it with examples

Comment: I don't know what the form (POST data) you are recieving. From the code you gave above, it seems that your input are arrays. 
You can do that:
$data[] = [ 'name'=> $request->input('name'), 'quantity'=> $request->input('quantity'), 'unit_price'=> $request->input('unit_price')] Only if you try to insert one Asset at the time.
Can you provide the code of the form you are trying to send?

Comment: You can use dd($request->all()) in your controller to see what your post request looks like and try to figure out what data you recieve. You can then dd() the data and see if it has then required format to create your object. I believe your mistake is the processing of the post request.

Comment: I just added a dd($request->all()); for further clarification for help

Comment: form data just added as well